# Should comments be removed when they hint to content that has been edited out for not making it public?

Tags: discussion

An example is personal identifying information in
[My supervisor plagiarised my bachelor thesis: what can I do about it?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17606/my-supervisor-plagiarised-my-bachelor-thesis-what-can-i-do-about-it)

It is in this question comment:

> @Neptune: I've removed the identifying content of your post. Although
>   I understand your situation, Ac.SE is not the place to accuse by name
>   your supervisor of plagiarizing. You should not expect us to decide
>   whether there has been plagiarism or not based on the actual content,
>   but only to provide you with the answers on how to deal with it. – 
>   user102 Mar 2 '14 at 12:34

Hints like this can also be in the question or answer body, like in answer https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/17627/13560 :

> As a last resort, you can contact the organisers of the conference, as
>   stated by just-learning, and give them the information that you also
>   gave us above (now deleted).

Another example is this question, as it now hints at the same deleted information indirectly.

Answer (score 2):

If a comment no longer stands on its own, this sounds like an intended use of the "obsolete" flag.  An answer, however, can simply be edited to reflect the current state of the question.